# Endpoint in WSDL to use in Android

Tags: java, android, wcf, wsdl

I am using wcf in android. However i am confused when i try to find endpoints. For example: what is the endpoint for this:

```
<xs:element name="getAllExamsResponse">
<xs:complexType>
     <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="getAllExamsResult" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Here getAllExamsresult is response json, right? also service name is:
 `<wsdl:service name="TusService"/>`

I am using in JAVA like:

```
 HttpPost request = new HttpPost(SERVICE);

      //  List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
      //  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserName", "sss"));
      //  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", "selen-01"));
      //  request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // set the hedear to get the data in JSON formate

        request.setURI(new URI(SERVICE + "/getAllExams"));
        request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

What is wrong here ?

EDIT: I am getting this error:

value doctype of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to jsonobject in android